# Verifying value isn't undefined in typescript inside a variable doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code:

```
interface A {
    data?: number
}
const acceptsNumber = (x: number) => {
    console.log(x)
}
const a: A = {
    data: 6
}
const doesAHasValue = a.data
if (doesAHasValue) {
    acceptsNumber(a.data)
}
```

And I get the following error for the last line(acceptsNumber(a.data)): 
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.  TS2345

But if I change the condition to

```
if (a.data) {
    acceptsNumber(a.data)
}
```

It transpiles fine. Why?

I know I can solve it by `acceptsNumber(doesAHasValue)` but I want to know why it doesn't transpile in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the type of `a.data` is `number | undefined` but the function requires a `number`.

However, when you do:

`if(a.data) { ... }` which resolves to `true`, TypeScript creates a "type-guard" and implicitly changes the type of `a.data` just inside the `{ ... }` to be `number`.

Once the type is `number` you get no errors.

You can read more about Type Guards [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

Comment: I expected ts to also understand that doesAHasValue is a number inside {...} since it references a.data and I don't change it and it can't be changed. Unless I write a.data=undefined and in this case I expect it to throw an error

Answer (score 0):

The issue which you are having is because TS is not able to follow relation between `doesAHasValue` and `a.data`. You indeed as a human look at the code and see this relation, as line before the condition you made the assignment - `const doesAHasValue = a.data`, and it looks obvious to see the relation. But for TS there is none, TS sees `doesAHasValue` as unique value, with type `number | undefined` and if you ask `if (doesAHasValue)` the only thing we are narrowing is exactly `doesAHasValue` to number(BTW that is why also `acceptsNumber(doesAHasValue)` works).

For TS assignment is only saying - I have the same type as the value on the right has. It is not saying - I am only alias bound to the original value. `doesAHasValue` and `a.data` share the same type and value, but are not bound together, checking one does not effect type of the second.

In your particular example such behavior of TS has a great sense, as we can mutate `a.data` after assignment. Check below code, nothing protects us from having different value in both places:

```
const doesAHasValue = a.data
a.data = undefined; // we set it undefined, doesAHasValue is still 6

if (doesAHasValue) {
    acceptsNumber(a.data) // a.data is undefined here
}
```

But for situation when we have real alias, and we use `const`, even then still TS is not connecting types. Consider:

```
const f = (arg: number | undefined) => {
    const a = arg;
    const b = a;
    if (b) {
        b // number
        a // number | undefined even though b is alias for a, so it theoretically could be narrowed
    }
}
```

In summary, compilator is not able to catch the connection between the original value `a.data` and the new one `doesAHasValue`. I assume tracking such relation would be overkill for compilation.

Comment: If in C# I check for a variable to not be null and then try to check again later, my ide will add a "warning" saying that I already checked the value to be null. Same thing can also work here. In my example there is no way that a.data will be undefined since js is single threaded